# How can I not break my html text when there isn't enough space for text

Tags: php, html, line-breaks, spacing

Sorry for the confusing title but I did not know how to ask this.

Basically I have a title of a drink and the quantity of the drink next to it like so.

```
Orange Juice ( 20 LT )
```

Im really using PHP to output the information but this is the code that would make that happen:

```
<h6><?php the_title(); ?> <span>&nbsp;(&nbsp;<?php the_field('quantity'); ?>&nbsp;)</span></h6>
```

I tried using the html space code but did not seem to work `&nbsp;`

So the problem is when the screen is to small and there isn't enough space the quantity `( 20 LT )` will go on to the next line but NOT the entire quantity just a part like so:

```
Orange Juice ( 20
 LT )
```

how can I make it so that if there is not enough space to output the quantity bring the entire quantity down to the next line and not just part of it.

Meaning if there weren't enough space it would look like this:

```
Orange Juice 
( 20 LT )
```

and **not** only bring a part of quantity down but the whole thing.

Comment: Try to add `display:inline-block` CSS to the `<span>`.

Comment: `h6 > span { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Both ways works guys thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `display: inline-block` to the span, like this:

`<h6><?php the_title(); ?> <span style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;(&nbsp;<?php the_field('quantity'); ?>&nbsp;)</span></h6>`

Comment: Works great, I just added that in my stylesheet. Also every way posted here works I just used display:inline-block because I already had styles for that span set up so it was just a matter of adding another simple style.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<span>` a class name like `<span class="nowrap">` and add this to your CSS

```
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can use usual spanes not `&nbsp;` inside that span.